# Get column of data from third level of a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, array-column

I have a multidimensional array with four levels of data.  Here's a small sample:

```
$data = [
    [
        [
            'Date' => '2021-03-15T00:00:00.0000000+01:00',
            'Arena' => ['Id' => 181796, 'Name' => 'Motala bibliotek'],
            'Description' => null,
            'IsCanceled' => null
        ],
        [
            'Date' => '2021-03-16T00:00:00.0000000+01:00',
            'Arena' => ['Id' => 181796, 'Name' => 'Motala bibliotek'],
            'Description' => null,
            'IsCanceled' => null
        ],
        [
            'Date' => '2021-03-17T00:00:00.0000000+01:00',
            'Arena' => ['Id' => 181796, 'Name' => 'Motala bibliotek'],
            'Description' => null,
            'IsCanceled' => null
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            'Date' => '2021-03-15T00:00:00.0000000+01:00',
            'Arena' => ['Id' => 181796, 'Name' => 'Motala bibliotek'],
            'Description' => null,
            'IsCanceled' => null
        ],
        [
            'Date' => '2021-03-16T00:00:00.0000000+01:00',
            'Arena' => ['Id' => 181796, 'Name' => 'Motala bibliotek'],
            'Description' => null,
            'IsCanceled' => null
        ]
    ]
];
```

I need to collect all of the `Date` values from the third level in the array.

I know how to loop through the top level, but I am at a loss for how to write the rest of the code to get the deeper `Date` elements.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
    echo $i;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Desired output:

```
array (
  0 => '2021-03-15T00:00:00.0000000+01:00',
  1 => '2021-03-16T00:00:00.0000000+01:00',
  2 => '2021-03-17T00:00:00.0000000+01:00',
  3 => '2021-03-15T00:00:00.0000000+01:00',
  4 => '2021-03-16T00:00:00.0000000+01:00',
)
```

Comment: Did you try another loop in that loop ? See also [`foreach`](https://php.net/foreach)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to extract a column of data from the third level of a multidimensional array.  Different techniques will have trade-offs.  The following demonstrations will all generate the same output.  ([Demo Link](https://3v4l.org/bnRrP))

### Eliminate top level of structure with spread operator before isolating columns

- ```
  array_column(array_merge(...$data), 'Date')
  ```
- Pros:

  - it is the most concise option
  - it does not iterate any data unnecessarily
  - `array_column()` doesn't need to check if the column key exists to avoid warnings
  - it perfectly fits into a codebase using functional stylings -- IOW, the return value is immediately accessible and no extra variable needs to be declared
- Cons:

  - if you, your development team, or your future development team are not familiar with [variadics](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/variadics), then this one-liner is not very intuitive. On the other hand, raising awareness of how to flattening an array will be good for your team; maybe just write a note in your code and link to a SO page or the php docs for quick reference.

### Check leaf-node keys recursively <sub>(not recommended)</sub>

- ```
  $result = [];
  array_walk_recursive(
      $data,
      function($v, $k) use (&$result) {
          if ($k === 'Date') {
              $result[] = $v;
          }
      }
  );
  ```
- Pros:

  - because `array_walk_recursive()` traverses leaf-nodes and 'Data' is always "scalar", all `Date` elements will be found
  - if the level structure changes, the code will still work because `array_walk_recursive` is level-ignorant
- Cons:

  - `array_walk_recursive()` traverses leaf-nodes, it will visit ALL scalar elements in the structure which means there will be some useless processing
  - not very concise and involves an anonymous function which requires $result to be declared as a modifiable-by-reference variable
  - if the data type of `Date` changes to something iterable, then it ceases to be a leaf-node

### Loop and push elements columns using the spreading operator

- ```
  $result = [];
  foreach ($data as $group) {
      array_push($result, ...array_column($group, 'Date'));
  }
  var_export($result);
  ```
- Pros:

  - it is not too verbose and does not involve an anonymous function (so no modifiable-by-reference variable)
  - it does not iterate any data unnecessarily
- Cons:

  - it doesn't lend itself to a functional programming style because a `$result` variable must be declared
  - if you, your development team, or your future development team are not familiar with [variadics](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/variadics); maybe just write a note in your code and link to a SO page or the php docs for quick reference.

### Classic nested foreach loops

- ```
  $result = [];
  foreach ($data as $group) {
      foreach ($group as $row) {
          if (array_key_exists('Date', $row)) {
              $result[] = $row['Date'];
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Pros:

  - probably the most intuitive/semantic for developers of any experience level
  - it does not iterate any data unnecessarily
  - it has minimal functional overhead* so it will potentially perform the best on huge data sets (be sure to benchmark if this is a reasonable concern)
- Cons:

  - it is completely procedural style and requires a `$result` variable to be declared
  - it is relatively verbose
- *The condition with `array_key_exists()` will not be necessary if the input data is guaranteed to contain the `Date` element on all levels. If they are not guaranteed to exist, then the condition serves to prevent warnings.

### A modern spin on classic nested loops

- ```
  $result4 = [];
  foreach ($data as $group) {
      foreach ($group as ['Date' => $result4[]]);
  }
  ```
- Pros:

  - Using array destructuring to access only the date value in the inner loop makes the snippet more succinct
  - it does not iterate any data unnecessarily
  - it has minimal functional overhead* so it will potentially perform the best on huge data sets (be sure to benchmark if this is a reasonable concern)
- Cons:

  - it is completely procedural style and requires a `$result` variable to be declared
  - it is less commin to see array destructuring in a `foreach()` as well as a body-less loop pushing data into a variable so your development team may not be familiar with the syntax.
  - the `Date` element must exist on all levels.